# Edebug orgmode source code blocks with input variables

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, debugging, edebug

What is the standard method to debug emacs-lisp orgmode source code blocks with input variables as header arguments?

I found the hacky solution to insert the following snipped in front of a source code block.

```el
(when t ;; t: do debug, nil: do not debug
  (org-edit-src-code)
  (let ((parse-sexp-ignore-comments t))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-sexp 2)
    (edebug-defun)))
```

Debugging of the source code block can be turned on or off by the boolean on the first line. The `org-edit-src-code` makes sure that point is in the special source edit buffer when one executes the source code block. The snippet puts point in front of the actual code and enters `edebug-defun`.

There follows a full working example:

```
* edebug emacs-lisp source code block with input variables

  Example input data:
  #+TBLNAME: input-table
  | This   | table       | contains |
  | some   | strings     | for      |
  | trying | source code | blocks   |

  Further example input data (strings to be highlighted):
  #+TBLNAME: emph
  | table | strings | blocks |

  The code-block to be debugged:
  #+NAME: emphDebug
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var input=input-table emph=emph
(when t ;; t: do debug, nil: do not debug
  (org-edit-src-code)
  (let ((parse-sexp-ignore-comments t))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-sexp 2)
    (edebug-defun)))
;; The actual program starts here.
(let ((re (regexp-opt (car emph))))
  (mapcar (lambda (row)
        (mapcar (lambda (col)
              (if (string-match re col)
              (concat "*" (match-string 0 col) "*")
            col))
            row))
      input))
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS: emphDebug
  | This   | *table*     | contains |
  | some   | *strings*   | for      |
  | trying | source code | *blocks* |
```

Place point on the `#+BEGIN_SRC` line and press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to start debugging.

---

If one often needs to debug source code blocks one can define the following function somewhere in his configuration file:

```el
(defun org-src-debug ()
  "Put a call to this function at the beginning of the org source block to debug it."
  (save-excursion
    (let ((pt (let ((case-fold-search t)) (org-babel-where-is-src-block-head))))
      (unless pt (error "Not at source block"))
      (goto-char pt)
      (org-edit-src-code)
      (let ((parse-sexp-ignore-comments t))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (forward-sexp 2)
        (edebug-defun)))))
```

This function can then be used at the beginning of source code blocks. Example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var test='(1 2 3)
   (org-src-debug)
   (message "arg: %s" test)
#+END_SRC
```

---

But, I guess there is some org-standard way for debugging which I am not yet aware of.

Comment: No standard way I know of: I usually write and debug the code outside of org and *then* create the source block.

Comment: @NickD `org-src-debug` above is a really handy alternative and worth a try. The most pleasent thing is that the header variables are already defined when the debugger is called.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @NickD 1st: I just checked. The elisp code I am currently using is still that one from above. 2nd: Only the first form in the source block is debugged. If you have a sequence of forms in your source block temporarily wrap them by `progn`.

Comment: Got it, thanks!