# macos org-babel python with session output give __PYTHON_EL_eval

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

```
#+begin_src python :session :results output
print("yes")
#+end_src
```

With `org-babel-execute-src-block` command, the result is:

```
#+RESULTS:
: __PYTHON_EL_eval("try:\n    with open('/var/folders/hh/lnftkrwn1tv9b63ptnphj_gm0000gp/T/babel-ww4KL0/python-AICyg8') as __org_babel_python_tmpfile:\n        exec(compile(__org_babel_python_tmpfile.read(), __org_babel_python_tmpfile.name, 'exec'))\nexcept:\n    raise\nfinally:\n    print('
```

not "yes".

`:results value` is behaved as expected.

Error message:

```
error in process filter: sort: Wrong type argument: stringp, (\, "python")
error in process filter: Wrong type argument: stringp, (\, "python")
Can’t guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4
```

Version:

```
GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0, Carbon Version 162 AppKit 1894.6)
 of 2022-04-28
org mode 9.5.3
```

Update: I find the error gone when I use python 3.9 instead of python 3.7. I do not understand the link between the issue and version of python, but it does fix the issue.

Comment: Which command was used? M-x org-babel-execute-src-block RET prints "yes" with GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.32, cairo version 1.16.0)

Comment: @AndreasRöhler `org-babel-execute-src-block`

Comment: Might be a bug. Please consider filing your question a <emacs-orgmode@gnu.org>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue, and I bugged someone much smarter than me about it -- her conclusion after some debugging was that it *seems* like this basically boils down to the Python that comes with MacOS not being compiled with readline support. This could be seen by opening a python shell in emacs, and entering 1, and seeing that the input is echoed in addition to being output.

We switched to using a different python installation (specifically the one that comes with nix) and this made the issue go away. (She says that ones that come with homebrew / macports would also work; apparently it's well-known that the python version that ships with MacOS has these kinds of problems.)

Slightly unsatisfying + seems like black magic to me, but it's working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question seeing the same error. Eventually I discovered how python sessions use buffers and how to inspect what went wrong from [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38751/38160).

If you don't specify a `:session` name, the default buffer is named `*Python*`. To continue using that session you can:

- switch to the buffer and inspect what may have gone wrong before this block was called and fix it up,
- call `reset` on the first line of the block, or
- use a new session name.

There may be other workarounds, including killing the session buffer.

I expect this would work on first try:

```
#+begin_src python :session xyzzy :results output
print("yes")
#+end_src
```

Unfortunately I've been unable to replicate the error since resolving it, but that would be helpful if this is considered a bug to fix.