# How to find START and END of #+RESULTS region with elisp functions?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to call `(recode-region)` on `sh` code block results in `:post` header attribute. 
So it needs `START` and `END` values. Is there a way to define of `RESULTS` block content boundaries for it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `org-element-parse-buffer` to obtain an abstract syntax tree (AST) of your org buffer.
Search that AST for the node representing the results of interest by `org-element-map`.
You get the beginning and the end of the region with the results of interest from the node by `(org-element-property :contents-begin node)` and `(org-element-property :contents-end node)`.
All addressed functions are well documented and also described in the [worg wiki](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html).

I demonstrate the outlined procedure by a documented example org-mode file below:

```org
* The source code block with the results of interest
  #+NAME: resultsOfInterest
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
'((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS: resultsOfInterest
  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
  | 4 | 5 | 6 |

* The source code block for the analysis
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results drawer
;; (org-src-debug) ;;< Remove first comment starters to use the debugging code from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13244/edebug-orgmode-source-code-blocks-with-input-variables
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; The following wrapper enables us to run the code
;; - by evaluating the source code block within the org-file and also
;; - by evaluating the form in the source edit buffer.
(with-current-buffer (or (and (org-src-edit-buffer-p) (org-src--source-buffer))
             (current-buffer))
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  ;; The actual code starts here:
  (when-let ((ast (org-element-parse-buffer)) ;; built up the abstract syntax tree of the org buffer
         (node (org-element-map
               ast
               'table ;;< We assume here that the results of interest are generated as table. Adapt to your case.
             (lambda (node)
               "Predicate for identifying the result of interest in the ast"
               (when (equal (org-element-property :results node) '("resultsOfInterest")) ;; Results of interest are marked by #+RESULTS: "resultsOfInterest".
             node))
             nil
             'first-match ;;< With 'first-match `org-element-map' works similar to `cl-find-if'.
             ))
         (beg (org-element-property :contents-begin node)) ;< Beginning of region with results of interest 
         (end (org-element-property :contents-end node))) ;< End of region with results of interest
    ;; Action on the results of interest:
    ;; We just output the region as result of this source block.
    (buffer-substring beg end)))
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  :RESULTS:
    | 1 | 2 | 3 |
    | 4 | 5 | 6 |
  :END:
```

Answer (score 1):

With point in a source block, the following snippet of code will return the start and end of the results as (RESULTS_START . RESTULTS_END):

```lisp
(unless (org-in-src-block-p)
    (error "Not in a source block"))
(let* ((src (org-element-context))
       (results-start (org-babel-where-is-src-block-result))
       (results-end
        (when results-start
          (save-excursion
            (goto-char results-start)
            (goto-char (org-babel-result-end))
            (point)))))
  ;; return the region as (RESULTS_START . RESULTS_END)
  `(,results-start . ,results-end))
```