# Pass org-babel header arguments to elisp function

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have an `org-babel` code block like so:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :var a=~/path/to/project

Do something here

#+END_SRC
```

How can I reference variable `a` without having to evaluate the block?

Comment: Variable `a` is defined only within the block, so you cannot reference it outside the block or without evaluating it. I'm not really sure what you want to do though: maybe expand the question a bit?

Comment: [This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13244/edebug-orgmode-source-code-blocks-with-input-variables) might help to give you some ideas, although it is almost certainly *not* what you are asking.