# Org-mode: Copy headings only and yank to contents

Tags: org-mode, copy-paste

I started from [this post](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/10/29/Add-subheadings-to-all-headings-in-an-org-file-at-some-level/) and now have code that already works for the following, for each level 2 heading:

1. Add properties drawer `:ANKI_NOTE_TYPE: Basic` to the level 2 heading.
2. Add two level 3 headings (`Front` and `Back`) with empty content.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results org raw
(let ((MATCH t)
      (SCOPE 'file)
      (SKIP nil)
      (spacing nil))
  (org-map-entries
         (lambda ()
               (let ((level (nth 1 (org-heading-components))))
                 (if (= level 2)
                     (save-restriction
                       (org-narrow-to-subtree)
                       ;; (org-copy-visible)
                       (org-entry-put (point) "ANKI_NOTE_TYPE" "Basic")
                       (goto-char (point-max))

                       (org-insert-heading)
                       (insert "Front \n")
                       ;; now cut tree and paste at level 3
                       (org-cut-subtree)
                       (org-paste-subtree 3)

                       (org-insert-heading)
                       (insert "Back \n")
                       ;; (yank)
                       ;; now cut tree and paste at level 3
                       (org-cut-subtree)
                       (org-paste-subtree 3)
                       )))) MATCH SCOPE SKIP))
#+END_SRC
```

The above is working as expected for my input org chunk:

```
* Rand
** What is marketing?
** What are the four Ps?
```

which returns

```
* Rand
** What's marketing?
:PROPERTIES:
:ANKI_NOTE_TYPE: Basic
:END:

*** Back 


*** Front 

** What are the four Ps?
:PROPERTIES:
:ANKI_NOTE_TYPE: Basic
:END:

*** Back 

*** Front
```

I'm now trying to copy the visible level 2 heading into the contents of the newly created level 3 heading, i.e. trying to get:

```
* Rand
** What is marketing?
:PROPERTIES:
:ANKI_NOTE_TYPE: Basic
:END:
*** Back 

*** Front 
What is marketing?

** What are the four Ps?
:PROPERTIES:
:ANKI_NOTE_TYPE: Basic
:END:
*** Back 

*** Front 
What are the four Ps?
```

In my code chunk, I've tried using `org-copy-visible` at line 12 then yanking at line 24 (as above, after uncommenting).

However `org-copy-visible` seems to be failing with:

```
save-restriction: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 2), 0
```

How should I copy the visible level 2 heading into the contents of the newly created level 3 heading?

**EDIT 1**: updated example to show behaviour with 2 level 2 headings.

Comment: What should happen when there is more that one visible level 2 heading?

Comment: It should copy each level 2 heading separately into its level 3 content. Updated question to show expected behavior.

Comment: I think you're taking pains to achieve something that might be more easily achieved using Org capture. `(info "(org) Capture")`

Comment: @PhilHudson: I don't know if you have the time, but I'd be very interested in a capture solution. I'm not sure *why* the OP wants this and my answer is purely a "don't ask questions: just do exactly what the OP asked" but it would be interesting to dig a little deeper and find out.

Comment: @NickD the crucial things to bear in mind are: 1. `%i`, `%c` (and to a lesser extent `%x`) are your friends. 2. `%(sexp "%i")` works as you'd hope. 3. In this case `file+function` is probably the right target type. 4. I might consider (ab)using the clock functionality (`clock` target, `%k` element) in this case.

Comment: I considered an `org-capture` solution, however it didn't seem to fit my needs exactly.

I would rather write an entire list of notes first, instead of capturing one-by-one.

Still between two minds but probably will be using the function. 

https://gist.github.com/whkoh/eb36ba14af29ce7a4f22dcf01a03a2e6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there already: `org-heading-components` returns a list of six elements (numbered from 0 to 5), the fifth of which is the text of the headline. So all you need to do is remember it and insert it in the right place:

```el
* Rand
*** What is marketing?                                                                                      :some:tag:
:PROPERTIES:
:ANKI_NOTE_TYPE: Basic
:END:

***** Back 


***** Front 
What is marketing?

*** What are the four Ps?
:PROPERTIES:
:ANKI_NOTE_TYPE: Basic
:END:

***** Back 


***** Front 
What are the four Ps?


* Code

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results org raw
  (defun whkoh/munge-tree ()
    (let ((MATCH t)
          (SCOPE 'file)
          (SKIP nil)
          (spacing nil))
      (org-map-entries
       (lambda ()
         (let* ((comps (org-heading-components))
                (level (nth 1 comps))
                (text (nth 4 comps)))
           (if (= level 2)
               (save-restriction
                 (org-narrow-to-subtree)
                 ;; (org-copy-visible)
                 (org-entry-put (point) "ANKI_NOTE_TYPE" "Basic")
                 (goto-char (point-max))

                 (org-insert-heading)
                 (insert "Front \n")
                 (insert (concat text "\n"))
                 ;; now cut tree and paste at level 3
                 (org-cut-subtree)
                 ;; org-paste-subtree does not know about reduced levels, only "real" levels
                 ;; if org-odd-levels-only is true, then reduced level 3 is real level 5,
                 ;; but if false, then both are 3.
                 (org-paste-subtree (if org-odd-levels-only 5 3))

                 (org-insert-heading)
                 (insert "Back \n")
                 ;; (yank)
                 ;; now cut tree and paste at level 3
                 (org-cut-subtree)
                 (org-paste-subtree (if org-odd-levels-only 5 3))
                 )))) MATCH SCOPE SKIP)))
#+END_SRC
```

The changes are:

- I created a function to wrap your code. That makes it easier to use a debugger (although @Tobias has shown some code that allows debugging of arbitrary Org Babel source blocks - see [Edebug orgmode source code blocks with input variables](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13244/edebug-orgmode-source-code-blocks-with-input-variables)). When you evaluate the code block, the function is defined. You can then call it in the Org mode buffer with `M-: (whkoh/munge-tree)`.
- I save the results of calling `org-heading-components` and grab two of those components: the (reduced) level with `(nth 1 comps)`, i.e. the second element of the list, and the text of the headline with `(nth 4 comps)`, i.e. the fifht element of the list.
- I then insert the saved text of the headline in the section entitled "Front" which is then moved bodily into (reduced) level three.

There is one important wrinkle: I've referred to the reduced level above - that's the "logical" level. The problem is that there is also a "physical" level which is the number of asterisks in front of the headline. In many (most?) cases, the "logical" level and the "physical" level are the same: they are both equal to the number of stars in front of the headline.

But Org mode allows a customization, `org-odd-levels-only`, which makes them different. If `org-odd-levels-only` is set to `t`, then the "logical" level (1, 2, 3, ...) corresponds to a "physical" level of (1, 3, 5, ...) stars.

If, as is likely, you are *not* using this customization, then you might
want to skip the rest of this explanation, but you should still keep the change that I made above. Without it, if you ever do customize `org-odd-levels-only` to `t` and run the code, you will get an infinite loop (DAMHIKT).

The problem is that `org-paste-subtree` does not know about logical levels, only physical ones.

There are different ways to deal with the problem, but I think the least confusing one is to deal with logical levels only. That's what `(nth 1 comps)` returns and that's what you use in the comparison `(if (= level 2) ...`. But what you use as the argument to `org-paste-subtree` has to be a physical level: that's 3 if `org-odd-levels-only` is `nil` (the default), but it should be 5 if it is customized to `t`. So the two calls to `org-paste-subtree` are slightly more complicated than what you have.
As I mentioned before, without that change, if `org-odd-levels` only is set to `t`, then the code produces an infinite loop.

If you want to learn more, search the Org manual for `org-odd-levels-only` for additional information about this. You can do that easily in Emacs, with `C-h i g(org)RET i org-odd RET`. There are four references, and you can use `,` to cycle through them and read them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Will take some time to digest it - I'm still a beginner in lisp evidently. I confess I've never encountered the emacs debugger but it looks pretty nice.

One newbie question: in `M-:`, why is the function called inside parens `(whkoh/munge-tree)` instead of just `whkoh/munge-tree`?

Comment: To call a function `func` with arguments in Lisp, you say `(func arg1 arg2 ...)`, e,g, to call the function `+` with arguments 2 and 3, you say `(+ 2 3)` which returns `5`. The function above is named `whkoh/munge-tree` and it takes no arguments, so to call it you say `(whkoh/munge-tree)`. See the [Emacs Lisp Intro manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Run-a-Program.html) for some details.